# Check which object invoked the ValueChanged Event of a Slider

Tags: c#, wpf, events, invoke

I am trying to determine which of my Sliders Invoked the Event, so I can call the OutputAnalogChannel Method with the Index of the Slider and the Slider value. 
My Sliders that could potentially invoke the Event are called:

{ K8055AnalogOutputSlider1, K8055AnalogOutputSlider2, [...], K8055AnalogOutputSlidern }

So nothing is wrong with the following code, it works, but I feel like this is a very 'bad' way of solving this problem. 
What i was thinking is that some kind of 'additional' integer value is added to the Slider which corresponds to the correct Slider at the Index.

Honestly this answer is probably hiding somewhere on stackoverflow, but I am not sure what I'd be searching for, so i posted here. Thanks in advance!

```
private void K8055AnalogOutputSliderValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Slider slider = sender as Slider;
    K8055.OutputAnalogChannel(int.Parse(slider.Name[slider.Name.Length - 1].ToString()), (int)slider.Value);
}
```

Comment: @VisualVincent The name property is already used, by the names stated above  { K8055AnalogOutputSlider1, K8055AnalogOutputSlider2, [...], K8055AnalogOutputSlidern }

Comment: You could use the controls' `Tag` property and set the index there.

Comment: I saw that, after formatting the code correctly. :)

Comment: Oh yes, Tag could work, I'll try it out now! Thanks!

Comment: Ah perfect! Create an answer so I can mark it as solved, Thanks!

Comment: Already ahead of you. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the controls' `Tag` property. Just set the property to the index of the control and then check it in your event handler:

```
K8055.OutputAnalogChannel((int)slider.Tag, (int)slider.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little more work, but it makes things incredibly easy to modify and maintain and read. It also gets you started taking advantage of some very powerful features of WPF. But if you're under severe deadline pressure, Vincent's quick fix has the virtue of simplicity.

C#

```
public class ChannelViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name = "";
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
        }
    }

    private int _channel = 0;
    public int Channel
    {
        get { return _channel; }
        set
        {
            _channel = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Channel)));
        }
    }

    private int _value = 0;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            K8055.OutputAnalogChannel(Channel, Value);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Channels.Add(new ChannelViewModel { Name="Fred", Channel = 1, Value = 3 });
        Channels.Add(new ChannelViewModel { Name="Bob", Channel = 2, Value = 35 });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ChannelViewModel> Channels { get; private set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ChannelViewModel>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

XAML

```
<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding Channels}"
    BorderBrush="Black"
    BorderThickness="1"
    >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                <TextBlock>Channel 
                    <Run Text="{Binding Channel, Mode=OneWay}" />: 
                    <Run Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" /></TextBlock>
                <Slider Value="{Binding Value}" Minimum="1" Maximum="100" Width="300" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I knew about data binding and MVVM, but had not the time to properly learn it. But I will definitely use this as a reference, once I eventually re-write it using that pattern. Thanks a lot!